# iPhone app on iPad: UILabel, UITextView text pixelated when viewed in 2x

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios6, uilabel

I tried my iPhone app (potrait mode) on iPad Mini just for a test... I noticed that when I tap 2x Mode the text in UILabel, UITextview appears pixelated.

In case of Images I have an option of setting images for both 1x & 2x mode (img1.png & img1@2x.png), but how to do this for text?

I don't want to create images with text for UILabel.

Comment: That's going to happen as long as you don't make an iPad version of the app. There's no other way of preventing that pixelation.

Answer (score 2):

As your app is for iPhone and you are trying to run this in iPad, it is showing like that. If you want it not to be pixeleted, you need iPad version of your app. @2x images are not to make your app compatible with iPad devices but for retina version of same devices.

Comment: True agreed, but even for retina version there might be some solution the iOS devs might have come up with so that the text is at least in a readable format & doesn't look pixelated

Answer (score 1):

Hinata is correct. you need to have a sparate iPad App for your Application so that it can run on iPad in full resolution mode. Go through the apple developer documents to know more about how to cerate iPad Application.

By default if you use universal as the build creator while creating your project the App will be supported on ipad's but they will run in 1X or 2X mode.

Let em know if you need more assistance on this.

Regards

Rajeev